# FormMixin on DetailView Django

Tags: python, django

I wanted to have a comment section in the same page as in my DetailView so I decided to use the FormMixin as a way to be able to add comments. It's not raising any errors but the submitted comments seem to be going nowhere and it's not showing up in the admin site also.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    video = EmbedVideoField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class PostComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.post} - {self.author}'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Fieldset, Button, Layout, Div, ButtonHolder, Field, Reset
from .models import Post, PostComment
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions
from django.urls import reverse

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.fields['body'].required = True
        self.fields['body'].label = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('body', style='max-height: 90px', placeholder='Write a comment...'),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Post', css_class='m-2 ms-3'),
                Reset('Reset This Form', 'Cancel', css_class='btn btn-secondary')
            ),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = PostComment
        fields = ['body','post',]
```

views.py
I mostly got this from the django documentations.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post, PostComment
from .forms import PostCreateForm, CommentForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'post': self.object})
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name = 'home-home'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name = 'post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post-detail'),
]
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'videosite/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% block body %}

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="card border-dark">
        <div class="row row-cols-2 gutter-0">
            <div class="col-7 pe-0" style="height: 526px;">
                <div class="card-body border-end border-dark">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        {% video posts.video '720x490' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 ps-0" style="height: 526px;">
                <div class="card-body bg-light" style="height: 526px;">
                    {% for comment in posts.comments.all %}
                        <a class="h5 text-dark text-decoration-none me-5" href="#"> {{ comment.author }}</a>
                        <span class="ms-3" >{{ comment.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</span>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ comment.body }} </p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% crispy form %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 pe-0" >
                <div class="card-body border-top border-end border-dark">
                    <h5><a class="fw-bold text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">{{ posts.title }}</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ posts.content }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body border-end border-dark" >
                    <span class="text-muted text-decoration-none">Posted by <a class="text-muted" href="#"> {{ posts.author }}</a> </span>
                    <span class="ms-3 text-muted" >{{ posts.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `PostDetailView` template related code?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, it's edited now.

Comment: As soon as you want to process a form, subclass FormView.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormView` not `DetailView` as your base class. I expect it'll all then work.

An invaluable resource is [Classy Class-based views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/). It shows that `DetailView` does not have a POST handler (method) and that `FormMixin` does not provide that either, which is probably why what you have is not working.

POST handling is defined by `FormView` itself.